# Complex Javascript Callback Scenario

Tags: javascript, callback

I have a scenario like this:

```
function sendRequest(args){
   //some stuff here
   request = buildRequest();
   return request;
}

function buildRequest(){
   //some stuff here
   asyncCall1(args,function(err,result){
      //some stuff here
        asyncCall2(args2, function(err2,result2){
           //some stuff here
           //final request that is build is here inside async2
           return request;//I dont know if this is the correct way
       });
   });
}
```

I need the **request** parameter which is available inside the **asynCall2's** callback method back to the **sendRequest** method so that I can return it form there.
I am very new to javascript as well as callbacks..all I need is to stop the execution of **sendRequest** method till I get the **request** parameter back from the **asyncCalls** (also how will I return that **request** parameter from **asyncCall2**).
The only constraint is I cannot change the signatures of **sendRequest**, **asyncCall1** and **asyncCall2** methods.

Comment: That's simply not possible (and doesn't make much sense if you'll take a moment to think about it). You're either synchronous, or you're asynchronous. You can't be both at the same time.

Comment: Can you be a little bit more comprehensive.. I am really new to this concept. I think i got your point but can you make this workflow correct?

Comment: Read up on the duplicate link.

Comment: @Amit Is it because I cant modify the signature of sendRequest method to support a callback?

Comment: I don't know anything about your sendRequest method. It looks like it is your code, so you can do whatever you want with it, but you'd really do yourself a big favor if you read the long and detailed answer in the duplicate link. seriously.

Comment: @Amit I am implementing a web service compliant to the standards of the Quickbooks webconnector where the signature of the sendRequest method is defined, So I cant really do anything about it. Its just that in my case, to send a request via the sendRequest method(as I dont have any choice there) I had to make some async calls to another server instance to fetch some data to prepare the request itself..Btw I read the duplicate link and it is quite enlightening..Thanks!..So i guess there is no work around for this then!